# Hyper-V Network Virtualization: NVGRE gateway: NAT error

Tags: scvmm

I have a Hyper-V 2016 cluster with different nodes. This cluster is managed by SCVMM 2016. We make use of Hyper-V Network Virtualization with 5 NVGRE gateways. This cluster runs 400 VM's in 200 virtual networks (education).

The system has been running for more than 6 months, but yesterday there was a problem with outgoing traffic (from inside the virtual networks to the internet). If we try to refresh a VM, it always ends with one error (and the only error in general):

Error (13641)
The specified subnet prefix must be between the starting and ending values for the range.
Starting value: 4
Ending value: 30

Recommended Action:
Specify a suitable subnet prefix.

We have already tried to reboot the cluster and the gateways. Refreshing the hosts (Get-SCVMHost | Read-SCVMhost -RunAsynchronously) works fine.

Suggestions?